# Using fscanf to read integers, strings, and real numbers

Tags: c, scanf

Having trouble reading the combination of integers, strings, and real numbers using fscanf. I admit that I am a novice programmer in C, yet I don't see why my code is not working properly.

The contents of sourcefile.txt, the file used by fscanf:

```
222 MSLET[Pa] 0-MSL 200507011200 200507021200 101226.063
223 MSLET[Pa] 0-MSL 200507011200 200507021200 9999.000
224 MSLET[Pa] 0-MSL 200507011200 200507021200 101217.063
222 PRMSL[Pa] 0-MSL 200507011200 200507021200 101226.063
223 PRMSL[Pa] 0-MSL 200507011200 200507021200 9999.000
```

My c code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void)
{
    FILE *input;
    input = fopen("C:/sourcefile.txt", "r"); 
    char var[30], level[30];
    int loc, datecycle, datevalid;
    float value;
                                                             
    while (fscanf(input,"%d %[^ ] %[^ ] %d %d %f", &loc, var, level,         
&datecycle, &datevalid, &value) == 6) {
        fscanf(input,"%d %[^ ] %[^ ] %d %d %f", &loc, var, level, &datecycle,  
&datevalid, &value);
        printf("%d %s %s %d %d %f\n", loc, var, level, datecycle,
datevalid,value);
    }                                                                                                       
                                              
    fclose(input);
    return 0;               
}
```

Output from C code:

```
223 MSLET[Pa] 0-MSL -1356451712 -1356441712 9999.000
222 PRMSL[Pa] 0-MSL -1356451712 -1356441712 101226.063
223 PRMSL[Pa] 0-MSL -1356451712 -1356441712 9999.000
```

Issue #1

1. Only 3 of the 5 lines were read. I don't understand why.
2. The printf output from datecycle and datevalid are not the same as the
   input. I don't understand why.

Issue #2

With respect to the string entries in column 2 (e.g. MSLET[Pa]), instead
of using [^ ] to read in the string (read until I encounter a space), I
may want to read until I encounter the "]" (e.g. the "]" in MSLET[Pa]).
My understanding is that I would write [^]]. Is that correct?

Any help that can be provided would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should explain "not working properly" (preferably showing the output you get and explaining how it differs to what you expected)

Comment: The values you read into `datecycle` and `datevalid` likely exceed the maximum size of an `int`. And you discard every second line.

Comment: To clarify, I was trying to output the input exactly, using fscanf and printf. By changing the while statement to "while (!feof(input)) {", I was able to read all lines. By replacing "float value;" with "double value;" and replacing specifier "%f" with "%lf", I was able to read and output the correct values (left of the decimal point) of datecycle and datevalid. Thanks M.M for your help.

Comment: [while(!feof(f)) is alwasy wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/6699433)

Comment: And please format the post properly. You are allowed to have more than one code block, and you must realize that Having the issue descriptions in a code block doesn't make sense. Especially not in the same block as the code. Also fix indentation.

Comment: You will want to read `datacycle` and `datevalid` as strings, store as strings and when the individual year, month, day, time is needed, parse the value from the stored strings. Currently, the values exceed the size storable as `int`. If you increased the storage to an 8-byte value, storage as a number would be possible, but later conversion to year, month, day time would be much more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

While an older question, it is deserving of an answer. The reason you are not obtaining valid data for `datacycle` and `datevalid` is because the input you are attempting to read using a conversion to `int` exceeds the value that is representable as an `int`. For example `200507011200` exceeds the maximum value represented by a signed integer by two orders of magnitude.

However, simply using a larger storage type to accommodate the values will lead to difficulty separating the year, month, date, time components of the strings later. A better approach is to read `datacycle` and `datevalid` as strings. You can later convert to a numeric value if needed, or more likely separate into year, month, day, time.

Additionally, reading with `fscanf()` directly is a fragile approach to reading your input file. A single error in the format of one line will corrupts the read of all data from that point forward.

Instead, reading each line into a buffer (character array) and then parsing into separate values with `sscanf()` decouples the read and conversion allowing each line to be read completely. In that case, if a line contains in invalid character, etc... only the parse of values from that one line will fail and all remaining lines can be read correctly.

Don't use *MagicNumbers* or hardcode filenames. Instead, either provide the filename as the first argument to your program (that's what `int argc, char **argv` arguments to `main()` are for), or prompt the user and take the filename as input. You should not have to recompile your code simply to read data from a different filename. `30` in your code is a *MagicNumber*. If you need a constant, `#define` one or use a global `enum`. For example:

```c
#define MAXC 1024       /* if you need a constant, #define on (or more) */
#define MAXVL  32
#define NELEM  16
```

Where `MAXC` is the maximum number of characters to read from each line (e.g. the size of your character array to hold the line), `MAXVL` for the size of `var` and `level` and `NELEM` the number of elements in your array to hold all values and a general constant of `16` to also use for the string size of `datacycle` and `datevalid` storage.

To hold each line of data so that it is available for processing by your program, create a struct that holds the values for `loc`, `var`, `level`, `datacycle`, `datevalid` and `value`, and simply declare an array of struct. That way when you read and convert each line, you can store the values in an array for use throughout your program, e.g.

```c
typedef struct {        /* store datacycle & datevalid as strings */
    char var[MAXVL], level[MAXVL], datacycle[NELEM], datevalid[NELEM];
    int loc;
    float value;
} mydata_type;
```

Taking the filename to read as the first argument to your program (or read from `stdin` by default if no value is given), you can do the following:

```c
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    char buf[MAXC];                             /* buffer to hold each line */
    size_t n = 0;                               /* array element counter */
    mydata_type arr[NELEM] = {{ .var = "" }};   /* array of struct */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
```

You can read and store each line until your array is full or you have reached the end of file by looping and reading each line into `buf` and then separating the values with `sscanf()` as discussed above, e.g.

```c
    /* while array not full and line read */
    while (n < NELEM && fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {
        mydata_type tmp;    /* temporary structure to parse data into */
        /* parse data from buf into temporary struct and VALIDATE */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%d %s %s %s %s %f", &tmp.loc, tmp.var, tmp.level,
                    tmp.datacycle, tmp.datevalid, &tmp.value) == 6) {
            arr[n] = tmp;   /* on success, assign to array element */
            n += 1;         /* increment element counter */
        }
        else {
            fputs ("error: invalid line format.\n", stderr);
        }
    }
```

Close the file when you are done and then use the data a needed in your program. By way of example, you can output each of the values read from each line while converting `datacycle` and `datevalid` into year, month, day and time using `sscanf()` as well. An example would be:

```c
void prn_mydata (mydata_type *arr, size_t n)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int mc, dc, yc, tc,     /* integer values for datacycle components */
            mv, dv, yv, tv;     /* integer values for datevalid components */
        
        /* parse string values for datacycle & datevalid into components */
        if (sscanf (arr[i].datacycle, "%4d%2d%2d%4d", &yc, &mc, &dc, &tc) != 4)
            return;
        if (sscanf (arr[i].datevalid, "%4d%2d%2d%4d", &yv, &mv, &dv, &tv) != 4)
            return;
        
        /* output results */
        printf ("\n%d\n%s\n%s\n%s  %d-%02d-%02d:%d\n"
                "%s  %d-%02d-%02d:%d\n%.3f\n", 
                arr[i].loc, arr[i].var, arr[i].level,
                arr[i].datacycle, yc, mc, dc, tc, 
                arr[i].datevalid, yv, mv, dv, tv, 
                arr[i].value);
    }
}
```

Putting it altogether into a sample program you would have:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1024       /* if you need a constant, #define on (or more) */
#define MAXVL  32
#define NELEM  16

typedef struct {        /* store datacycle & datevalid as strings */
    char var[MAXVL], level[MAXVL], datacycle[NELEM], datevalid[NELEM];
    int loc;
    float value;
} mydata_type;

void prn_mydata (mydata_type *arr, size_t n)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int mc, dc, yc, tc,     /* integer values for datacycle components */
            mv, dv, yv, tv;     /* integer values for datevalid components */
        
        /* parse string values for datacycle & datevalid into components */
        if (sscanf (arr[i].datacycle, "%4d%2d%2d%4d", &yc, &mc, &dc, &tc) != 4)
            return;
        if (sscanf (arr[i].datevalid, "%4d%2d%2d%4d", &yv, &mv, &dv, &tv) != 4)
            return;
        
        /* output results */
        printf ("\n%d\n%s\n%s\n%s  %d-%02d-%02d:%d\n"
                "%s  %d-%02d-%02d:%d\n%.3f\n", 
                arr[i].loc, arr[i].var, arr[i].level,
                arr[i].datacycle, yc, mc, dc, tc, 
                arr[i].datevalid, yv, mv, dv, tv, 
                arr[i].value);
    }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    char buf[MAXC];                             /* buffer to hold each line */
    size_t n = 0;                               /* array element counter */
    mydata_type arr[NELEM] = {{ .var = "" }};   /* array of struct */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
    
    /* while array not full and line read */
    while (n < NELEM && fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {
        mydata_type tmp;    /* temporary structure to parse data into */
        /* parse data from buf into temporary struct and VALIDATE */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%d %s %s %s %s %f", &tmp.loc, tmp.var, tmp.level,
                    tmp.datacycle, tmp.datevalid, &tmp.value) == 6) {
            arr[n] = tmp;   /* on success, assign to array element */
            n += 1;         /* increment element counter */
        }
        else {
            fputs ("error: invalid line format.\n", stderr);
        }
    }
    
    if (fp != stdin)        /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);
    
    prn_mydata (arr, n);    /* print the results */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your example data in `dat/sourcefile.txt`, you would use the program and receive the following output where each component of the line is printed on a separate line as part of a group:

```
$ ./bin/read_sourcefile dat/sourcefile.txt

222
MSLET[Pa]
0-MSL
200507011200  2005-07-01:1200
200507021200  2005-07-02:1200
101226.062

223
MSLET[Pa]
0-MSL
200507011200  2005-07-01:1200
200507021200  2005-07-02:1200
9999.000

224
MSLET[Pa]
0-MSL
200507011200  2005-07-01:1200
200507021200  2005-07-02:1200
101217.062

222
PRMSL[Pa]
0-MSL
200507011200  2005-07-01:1200
200507021200  2005-07-02:1200
101226.062

223
PRMSL[Pa]
0-MSL
200507011200  2005-07-01:1200
200507021200  2005-07-02:1200
9999.000
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.